Sum of products of Fourier coefficients in finite field
Let $\mathbb{F_q}$ be some finite field and let $f,g: \mathbb{F_q} \to \mathbb{C}$.
By $\hat{f}, \hat{g}$ let's denote the Fourier coefficients of $f,g$ with respect to the additive characters of the field.
How good an upper bound can we exhibit for the following sum (if it's possible to find a non-trivial bound)
$$\left| \ \sum_{\{a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{F_q} : a^2+ab=c^2+cd \}} \hat{f}(a)\cdot \overline{\hat{f}(c)}\cdot \hat{g}(b)\cdot \overline{\hat{g}(d)}\ \right| ?$$
I care about the particular case that $f,g$ are indicator functions, but I don't see how this should play a role here.
What about optimal (general) bounds for the sum $\sum_{a\in \mathbb{F}^{*}_q} \left| \hat{f}(a) \right|$?
I could trivially bound the latter sum in this case by $|S|$, but I was wondering if there is something better. We could also use Cauchy-Schwarz and then Plancherel's equality, but I was also wondering if there is a better bound for indicator functions.

If $f$ has no particular form, then $\hat{f}$ has no particular form...

@mathworker21 For some problems of this type, knowing that $\hat{f}$ has no particular form, i.e. that $\hat{f}$ does not correlate strongly with any function on some explicit list, is sufficient to give a nontrivial bound.

For the second question, the Cauchy-Schwarz-Plancherel bound will be close to optimal for a random set.

@WillSawin I did not mean "$\hat{f}$ does not correlate strongly with any function on some explicit list" when I said "$\hat{f}$ has no particular form". I meant that $\hat{f}$ can be literally anything if $f$ can be anything. So there's no point to having fourier transforms in the problem.

@mathworker21 True, one may as well use $f$ and $g$ and then refer to the special case that $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{g}$ are Fourier transforms of indicator functions.

I would do this:
First detect the equation with additive characters, then reverse the Fourier transforms on the $g$'s, then break into subsums
$$ \sum_{\{a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{F_q} : a^2+ab=c^2+cd \}} \hat{f}(a)\cdot \overline{\hat{f}(c)}\cdot \hat{g}(b)\cdot \overline{\hat{g}(d)} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{q} \sum_{\{a,b,c,d , \lambda \in \mathbb{F}_q \}}  \psi( \lambda( a^2+ab-c^2-cd)) \hat{f}(a)\cdot \overline{\hat{f}(c)}\cdot \hat{g}(b)\cdot \overline{\hat{g}(d)} $$
$$= \sum_{a,c,\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_q } \psi ( \lambda (a^2-c^2))\hat{f}(a)\cdot \overline{\hat{f}(c)}\cdot g(\lambda a)\cdot  \overline{g(\lambda c)} $$
Now for any $u \in \mathbb F_q$ not equal to $0,1,$ or $-1$, the sum over the subset where $c = a u $ and $a\neq 0$ is possible to control: It is
$$\sum_{a,\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_q , a\neq 0 } \psi ( \lambda a^2 (1-u^2) )\hat{f}(a)\cdot \overline{\hat{f}(a u)}\cdot g(\lambda a)\cdot  \overline{g(\lambda a u )} $$
$$\sum_{a,b\in \mathbb{F}_q , a\neq 0 } \psi ( a b (1-u^2) )\hat{f}(a)\cdot \overline{\hat{f}(a u)}\cdot g(b)\cdot  \overline{g(b u )} $$
which by Plancherel and Cauchy-Schwarz is bounded by
$$ \sqrt{q \sum_{a \in \mathbb F_q,a\neq 0 } \left | \hat{f}(a)\cdot \overline{\hat{f}(a u)} \right|^2 \sum_{b \in \mathbb F_q}   \left |  g(b)\cdot  \overline{g(b u )} \right|^2} $$
so the sum over all such $u$ is bounded by
$$\sqrt{q} \sum_{u \in \mathbb F_q, u\neq 1,0,-1} \sqrt{ \sum_{a \in \mathbb F_q,a\neq 0 } \left | \hat{f}(a)\cdot \overline{\hat{f}(a u)} \right|^2 \sum_{b \in \mathbb F_q}   \left |  g(b)\cdot  \overline{g(b u )} \right|^2} $$
$$ \leq \sqrt{q}\sqrt{\left(\sum_{u \in \mathbb F_q, u\neq 1,0,-1} \sum_{a \in \mathbb F_q,a\neq 0 } \left | \hat{f}(a)\cdot \overline{\hat{f}(a u)} \right|^2  \right)  \left( \sum_{u \in \mathbb F_q, u\neq 1,0,-1} \sum_{b \in \mathbb F_q}  g(b)\cdot  \overline{g(b u )}\right)}$$
$$ \leq \sqrt{q} ||f||_2^2 ||g||_2^2$$
The remaining terms are those where $c=a, c=-a, c=0, a=0$, or all $4$ of these conditions are satisfied. These terms will be lower-order for generic $f,g$ but can lead to the main term for special $f,g$, and in any case their size can be estimated in the same elementary way.

So, in general, a good bound is $ ||f||^2 ||g||^2 O(\sqrt{q}) $ ?

A further standard device is to average a bound over all functions, to have at least a heuristic for "random" functions.

@User I think it's pretty good. Note that there are choices for how to normalize the Fourier transform and the $L^2$ norm that drastically affect the shapes of bounds. I am normalizing the Fourier transform to be unitary and the $L^2$ norm so that the constant function $1$ has $L^2$ norm $\sqrt{q}$. The second one may be less standard. I would consider $||f||^2 ||g||^2O (q)$ to be trivial in this context so the bound I sketch would be nontrivial.

@WillSawin Oh, I just noticed the comment about normalization. So, the bound is very different if $\langle f, g \rangle : = 1/|q| \sum_{x\in \mathbb{F_q}} (f(x) \overline{g(x)})$ and so, in particular, $\hat{f}(a)=\langle f, \psi_a \rangle = 1/|q| \sum_{x\in \mathbb{F_q}} (f(x) \overline{\psi_a(x)} ) $ ?

@User With that normalization it should be $||f||^2 ||g||^2 O(\sqrt{q})$ again because the two changes cancel out.

@WillSawin I see that now, thanks. The only detail I am missing is what exactly you mean be "Plancherel" before applying Cauchy-Schwarz, so basically the first inequality that appears.

@User The sum before that inequality is a dot product of the Fourier transform of $\hat{f} (a) \overline{\hat{f}(au)}$ with $g(b) \overline{g(bu)}$ (it's crucial that $1- u^2\neq 0$ for this). So maybe it's better described as first Cauchy-Schwarz then Plancherel.
